# Hippo CMS resets the mapped domain configuration data after rebuild

Tags: maven, content-management-system, hippocms, domain-mapping

I have installed an instance of Hippo CMS (version 7) and I already mapped a domain to a website. I also have an external repository for Hippo.

The problem is, Hippo will reset all of my domain mapping data if I clean the project by maven. Any rebuild command will be effect my domain mappings on Hippo. How can I solve this problem.

Note: after rebuild, I can see all of the documents in the CMS browser and console except domain mapping configurations.

Answer (score 0):

are you using auto-export? if not I would look at the bootstrap module:
bootstrap/configuration/src/main/resources/hst/configurations/{sitename}/sitemap.xml.

This is the file it will bootstrap everytime you do a mvn clean install (or verify).

If you add your changes to this xml (or turn auto-export on when making your sitemap changes) they will be reloaded once your rebuild your site.

Regards,
Dodo